# struts2 static method invoke issue

Tags: java, struts2

In struts2 I know that we can call static methods via OGNL. I have been trying to call this static method since afternoon now and cant seem to find out what the issue is.

struts.xml config:

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true" />
```

jsp page:

```
.....<s:property value='@com.aesthete.csmart.web.server.fw.common.config.Properties@getDefaultProperty("maxdemocountwords")'/>....
```

Properties.java

```
public static String getDefaultProperty(String key){
        return defaultProps.getProperty(key);
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What actually happens? Seems fine, except for the ridiculously-deep package.

Comment: The value does not appear on the jsp page. If I declare getDefaultProperty() in the action and in turn call Properties.getDefaultProperty() from that method then it works. Not directly though via static method call though..

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, other than make sure the fully-qualified name is correct, and the property key you're passing is right--the syntax and constant are correct, and AFAIK work across all versions.

Comment: You know what.. I give up! I am just going hard code the thing! Too much trouble.. Thanks

Comment: It's no trouble at all, because it works out-of-the-box. Without version info, proof you're using the right package/key, not much anyone can do. You can also just expose the value through the action--hardcoding is the wrong solution.

Comment: I agree about the hard coding. Thats why I am spending 2-3 hours on this :( . Exposing the thing via the action was my last resort actually. I have about 3 entry points to this jsp. I need to put the same method in all these actions. Still better than hard coding. I am positive about the class.method because .. well.. in eclipse you can click on copy qualified name and get the correct name. The property value also exists..

Comment: Then either the config file isn't being loaded, the constant is being overwritten by another config file, the JSP isn't being deployed as you expect, etc. AFAIK this functionality has never not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check, that `struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess` property in your `struts.properties` is set to `true`?

Comment: yup thats true. It still doesnt work. I have given up and hard coded it.

Answer (score -1):

Worked for me, but be aware that it is no more possible now :
[read official Struts documentation](http://struts.apache.org/docs/security.html#Security-Accessingstaticmethods)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow.

Comment: And if it is 'no more possible' then why do you give this as an answer?